# Writing to Excel file in specific format using Perl

Tags: excel, perl, csv

How would I print a csv file line that looks like:

string1,string2,string3,string4

string5,string6,string7,string8

.

to an Excel file that looks like:

string1 string2 string3 string4

string5 string6 string7 string8

.

with string1 and string5 being in column A, 2 and 6 in columnB, etc?

I just started using Perl and I am not sure how to approach this. Thank you!

Comment: Start here: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=perl+excel+write

Answer (score 2):

Programming is all about solving problems. But sometimes a problem is really big and seems too complicated. What you need to do then is break it down into smaller problems that are easier to solve.

You say you want to turn a CSV file into an Excel file. You will have to decide if you want [XLS or XLSX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel#File_formats) first. Both formats look the same when you open them in Excel, but they are actually very different under the hood.

When solving something in Perl, the first place to search is always [metacpan](https://metacpan.org/). Let's try:

- XLS: https://metacpan.org/search?q=write+excel leads to https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::WriteExcel
- XLSX: https://metacpan.org/search?q=excel+xlsx leads to https://metacpan.org/pod/Excel::Writer::XLSX

I'll pick Excel::Writer::XLSX. The [Quick Start part of the docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/Excel::Writer::XLSX#QUICK-START) suggests this to make a file and write one column.

> ```
> use Excel::Writer::XLSX;                                   # Step 0
>
> my $workbook = Excel::Writer::XLSX->new( 'perl.xlsx' );    # Step 1
> $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet();                   # Step 2
> $worksheet->write( 'A1', 'Hi Excel!' );                    # Step 3
>
> $workbook->close();                                        # Step 4
> ```

Now we know where to look to write to an Excel file. But there are still some problems. Let's break the whole thing down.

Googling "How do I read a CSV file in Perl?" gives us [this article](https://perlmaven.com/how-to-read-a-csv-file-using-perl) as the first hit. It has a couple of solutions (as is often the case in Perl). The best one is using Text::CSV, as it does all the work for you. Again, refer to [the documentation on metacpan](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV#SYNOPSIS) for more details.

> ```
> # Object interface
> use Text::CSV;
>
> my @rows;
> # Read/parse CSV
> my $csv = Text::CSV->new ({ binary => 1, auto_diag => 1 });
> open my $fh, "<:encoding(utf8)", "test.csv" or die "test.csv: $!";
> while (my $row = $csv->getline ($fh)) {
>     $row->[2] =~ m/pattern/ or next; # 3rd field should match
>     push @rows, $row;
>     }
> close $fh;
> ```

Of course this is not entirely what you want, but it's a good start.

Now you need to iterate over each line and take each column, and write that into the Excel file. I will assume you know how to iterate over a list. The above example already does that. What we need to do exactly is this:

- for every line in the CSV file

  - take each column value of the CSV file ...
  - ... and put it into the corresponding column in your Excel file
- save the Excel file

If you are having problems with those steps now, you can search for more specific problems.

---

Many Perl modules come with examples. If you look at the release on metacpan, you will see there are quite a few for [Excel::Writer::XLSX](https://metacpan.org/release/Excel-Writer-XLSX). Click the name of the module to go to the distribution page, and scroll down.

[image: click this link]

Text::CSV comes with similar examples too.